# Android gradle compile volley error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley

I just added the volley from Jcenter :

```
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

But I get the following error when syncing Gradle :

```
Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'has()'
```

This is my gradle project file :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my module gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dash.dashapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.mindorks:placeholderview:0.2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the line in Volley's bintray.gradle file from

```
publish = project.has("release")
```

to

```
publish = project.hasProperty("release")
```

Comment: I've seen this answer before unfortunately I decided to import the project with Gradle, therefore I don't have access to the bintray.gradle file